# how to remove default text in Itext fabric js

Tags: html5-canvas, fabricjs

At the moment I ' m working on one project with fabricjs . In project I use Itext from fabricjs to add text in canvas. I want when the user click on default text then auto remove default text. I use this code.

```js
$("#addText").on("click", function addText() {
  var oText = new fabric.IText('Tap and Type', { 
    left: 120, 
    top: 120,
    fontFamily: 'Bree Serif',
 fontSize: 22,
    cache:false
   
});
      $('#oText').css('fontSize', $('#fontSize').val() + 'px');

   oText.set({ fill: $(".addText-options .sp-preview-inner").css("background-color") });
   oText.id = 'userDesign';
   canvas.add(oText);
   
   currentObject.getColor(tinycolor.toRgbString());
   canvas.renderAll();
   saveCanvasState();
 })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this...
Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Jonah/sbtoukan/1/

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('container');

 var oText = new fabric.IText('Tap and Type', { 
     left: 0, 
     top: 0,
     fontFamily: 'Bree Serif',
     fontSize: 22,
     cache:false
 });

canvas.on("text:editing:entered", clearText);

 function clearText(e){
    if(e.target.type === "i-text"){
        if(e.target.text === "Tap and Type"){
            e.target.text = "";
            canvas.renderAll();
         };
     }
  }

  canvas.add(oText);
```

Comment: Big thanks it work perfect . I have one more question if it posible after clear text is there any way the box with text stay same size not to small.

Comment: There is no easy way as far as I know.

Comment: The best way would be to add a surrounding group around your text, set a border on the surrounding group and let the surrounding group redirect the click event into the iText. You would have to expand the group when the iText expands though...

Comment: Thanks at the moment i think this is best solution for me.

Comment: Great! Please mark the question as answered, and have a great day!

Answer (score 2):

You can also check out this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/xpntggdo/8/ . I have implemented some additional functionalities from my side such as dynamic width text box. In this, the width keeps on increasing until the boundary of canvas is reached.

You might have noticed that if you set a predefined width at the time of object creation, the text automatically goes to the next line. I hope this code or atleast some parts of this code might help you with whatever you are working on.

```
textBox.on("editing:entered", function (e) {
    var obj = canvas.getActiveObject();
    console.log("entered editing");
    if(obj.text == "Enter Text")
    {
        obj.selectAll();
        obj.removeChars();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Expanding upon some of the answers above for Fabric 2.0, `removeChars()` appears to be broken. Here's a work-around:

```
textObj.on("editing:entered", function (e) {
    var obj = canvas.getActiveObject();
    if(obj.text === DEFAULT_MSG)
    {
        obj.selectAll();
        obj.text = "";
        obj.hiddenTextarea.value = "";
        obj.dirty = true;
        obj.setCoords();
        canvas.renderAll();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

U can try this code.

```
var textFunctions = {

textEditing: function(e) {
    if (e.target.type == 'i-text') {
        if (typeof e.target.text == 'string' && e.target.text == 'Tap and Type') {
            textFunctions.textChanging();
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
},
textChanging: function() {
    return document.onkeydown = function(e) {
        if (e.target.value == 'Tap and Type') {
            var obj = canvas.getActiveObject();
            obj.selectAll();
            obj.setCoords();
            canvas.renderAll();
        }
    };
},

textNull: function(e) {
    if (e.target.type == 'i-text') {
        if (typeof e.target.text.length == 'number' && e.target.text.length == 0) {
            var obj = canvas.getActiveObject();
            obj.set({ 'text': 'Tap and Type' });
            obj.setCoords();
            canvas.renderAll();
        }
    }
}
}

    canvas.on('text:editing:entered', textFunctions.textEditing);
    canvas.on('text:editing:exited', textFunctions.textNull);
```